# Mongodb connection only once in next js

Tags: database, mongodb, next.js

I just started with Next js. The question I have is that in express projects we have a connection to the database once and we put it in the main file of the program, i.e. app.js. but in Next js as I understand so far, the connection to the database must be inside the api file. Doesn't this cause the connection to be reconnected every time the api is called? Is it necessary to have a file like app.js in order to connect to mongo inside it?
thanks

Comment: You can define a separate function to handle DB connection and check if the database is already connected to avoid further `connect` calls. Can you post the file or function where you handle the DB connection?

Answer (score 5):

create one separate file and add following code in that file.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const connection = {}

const dbConnect = async () => {
    if (connection.isConnected) return

    const db = await mongoose.
        connect(process.env.DB_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

    connection.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState
}
export default dbConnect
```

now only you need to call dbConnect() function every where you are performing the db operation.